# Как подсчитать максимальную пропускную способность интерфейса DVI?

Tags: видео, железо

Объясните, как это делается:

> размер видео-фрейма 600x800, какой будет максимальная пропускная способность для интерфейса DVI (фреймов/c) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Пропускная способность интерфейса DVI составляет 3,7 Гбит/с в режиме Single Link и 7,4 Гбит/с в режиме Dual Link, а максимальное разрешение передаваемого видеосигнала составляет 1920х1200 и 2560x1600 соответственно. В обоих случаях частота развертки равна 60 Гц. Изображение при передаче через DVI кодируется в 24-битном цвете.

Считаем.

Single Link:

```
3.7Гбит/с / (800*600*24 бит/кадр) ≈ 345 кадров
```

Dual Link:

```
7.4Гбит/с / (800*600*24 бит/кадр) ≈ 690 кадров
```

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

По спецификации для 
Single link 3.96 Гбит/с, для Dual link  7.92 Гбит/с , но это с поправкой на кодирование 8/10 , без поправки это 4.95Гбит/с и 9.90 Гбит/с соотвественно